# Can I use Azure Active Directory to hold my application's user store?

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm designing a solution for an ERP requirement. The Client insists on using AAD for one point management of users for different applications.

Since AAD has the capability of rendering Oauth service, I'm intending to use it as my OAUTH server and utilize its tokens inside my WebAPI services. But was wondering how I can capture the failed user login attempts as I need to apply locking mechanism.

When I found that AAD can handle this locking mechanism also through some configurations, I'm now left out with a question whether I can just use AAD for my user store, meaning I will have the users, their credentials and their roles stored in AAD, while I will have the permissions for each role and other data stored in my application's database.

Is this a feasible solution? or is there a different way of handling this?

**Note: We are using noSQL database.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a feasible solution. You can use [application roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles) to assign roles to users.

You can define the application roles by adding them to the application manifest. Then you can assign these roles to a user.

```
"appRoles": [
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
    "displayName": "SurveyCreator",
    "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyCreator"
  },
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Administrators can manage the Surveys in their tenant",
    "displayName": "SurveyAdmin",
    "id": "c20e145e-5459-4a6c-a074-b942bbd4cfe1",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyAdmin"
  }
],
```

The user list with roles listed.

[image]